# Applying a symbol as a procedure

Tags: scheme

Suppose I have a simple symbol:

```
> '+
+
```

Is there any way I can apply that symbol as a procedure:

```
> ((do-something-with '+) 1 2)
3
```

So that `'+` is evaluated to the procedure `+`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but would:

```
((eval '+) 1 2)
```

work? I'm not sure if you need to specify the environment, or even if that works - I'm a Scheme noob. :)

Comment: So simple, dunno how I missed that out. Thx! :)

Comment: If you want it to work with _any_ environment you should probably use `(eval '+ (null-environment 5))`

Answer (score 3):

Lucas's answer is great.  For untrusted input you can make a white list of allowed symbols/operators.

```
(define do-something (lambda (op)
                       (cond
                         ((equal? op `+) +)
                         ((equal? op `-) -)
                         ((equal? op `*) *)
                         ((equal? op `/) /)
                         ((equal? op `^) ^))))

((do-something `+) 1 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Newbie too so hope I've understood your question correctly...

Functions are first class objects in scheme so you don't need eval:

```
1 ]=> (define plus +)

;Value: plus

1 ]=> (plus 2 3)

;Value: 5
```

HTH

Update: Ignore this and see the comments!

Comment: @Ben - you missed the part where the `+` is quoted, hence, it is not directly a procedure until it is evaluated.