# Simple interpreter in Scheme

Tags: scheme, interpreter

I will describe my problem on example.

I'll get `(play '(left nothing right left))`. Some of the names in the list are real procedures, others i want to skip.

```
(define (left)
   'left
)
```

I need to interpret procedures with names in the list. What is the solution?

When I try `( (car '(left nothing right left)))` I get error : procedure application: expected procedure, given: left (no arguments)

Answer (score 4):

`(car '(left nothing right left))` evaluates to the symbol `left`, which is *the name of* a procedure, but not actually a procedure, so you can't call it.

You'll want to build an association list mapping symbols to procedures:

```
(define actions `((left . ,(lambda () 'left))
                  (right . ,(lambda () 'right))
                  (nothing . ,(lambda () (display "I'm staying put")))))
```

then you can call the appropriate function for the first element in your list as

```
((cdr (assoc (car '(left nothing right left)) actions)))
```

Comment: This is returning me again symbol left, not procedure but thank you. Your advice use symbol . procedure pair help me to find this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1834145/1226100 for almost same problem and I think that it is doing exactly what I want.

Comment: @Houp: this is giving you a symbol because your function returns a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use quasiquoting to construct a list containing a mixture of symbols you want evaluated and others you don't, e.g.

```
(play `(,left nothing nothing ,right nothing))
```

`left` and `right` will expand to whatever you've defined them as (such as a procedure) while `nothing` is not un-quoted so it will be left as a symbol.  `play` would then have to test each member to see if it's a procedure, something like:

```
(define (play xs)(for-each (lambda (x)(if (procedure? x)(x) x)) xs))
```