# How do I evaluate a symbol in MIT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I have a following in Scheme:

```
((car '(null? null?)) ())
```

which should evaluate to #t but I'm getting an error:

```
the object null? is not applicable
```

I tried some of the solutions in other SO questions but none of them seems to work.

How do I evaluate a symbol?

Comment: I didn't slept last night so I'll be brief: `((car (list null? null?)) '())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a symbol as a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775369/applying-a-symbol-as-a-procedure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not evaluate to `#t`. You are mixing symbols and variables. The second you quote something it's the code representation that becomes data.

```
'(null? null?)
; ==> (null? null?)
```

That is a list with two symbols. They have *noting* to do with:

```
null? 
; ==> #<procedure:null?> (implementation dependent visualization)
```

When you evaluate the **variable** `null?` you get the closure object. If you want to make a assoc of primitives you need to use `list` or `cons` to not quote the variables or you need to use quasiquote-syntax:

```
(define *primitives* 
  `((null? . ,null?)
    (car . ,car) 
    (cdr . ,cdr)))
```

This is just syntax sugar for using `list` and `cons`. 
When you evaluate this you notice right side isn't symbols:

```
*primitives*
; ==> ((null? . #<procedure:null?>)
;      (car . #<procedure:car>)
;      (cdr . #<procedure:cdr>))
```

Again. The visualization of a procedure differs. Here is how you can use it:

```
(define prim 'car)
(let ((found (assq prim *primitives*)))
  (if found
      ((cdr found) '(1 2 3))
      'signal-error))
```

Comment: (`(add1)`). the short answer could be: "you *don't*. *ever*. (evaluate a symbol in Scheme)."

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Sylwester shows the right way to understand the problem. I will try to make it simpler.

(i) The problem arise with every function, not only with the function "null?".

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
((car '(square square) 2) ---> The object square is not applicable. 
((car (list square square) 2) ---> 4
```

(ii) To reduct the problem to more simple expressions:

```
(car '(square)) ---> square
(car (list square)) --->  (#[compound-procedure 20 square])

(symbol? (car '(square)))        ---> #t
(procedure? (car (list square))) ---> #t
```

(iii) Before reading your question and sylwester's answer I thought that
'(square) and (list square) are the same thing.